# Time travelling

Tags: vedas, puranas, scripture, time, bhavishya-purana

There are some instances which show relative comparisons of time on different lokas. 
For example, Brahma took the cowherd boys who were with Krishna to Brahma loka and came back in a moment, but by that time 1 year had passed away on earth.

But I've never heard of any instances of time travelling in Hinduism. Are there any such instances in any Hindu scriptures where a person/demigod might have gone into the future or past to perform a certain task.

Comment: I don't think that such a notion even exists in Hinduism

Comment: Lookup interstellar travel and the side effects of time associated with it.

Comment: @Xarcell Haven't watched it yet. I need to watch it soon

Comment: @Surya Even i thought the same but just wanted to know whether any instance of it is mentioned somewhere in the scriptures.

Comment: Refer story of kakudmi https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakudmi

Comment: @sysinit An amazing account but it's essentially not a very different example I mentioned in the question.

Comment: Krsna says 'Kalo asmi Lokakshaya krt pravrddho' meaning 'I am Time, the great Destroyer of Worlds'. Therefore I don't think that it is possible to override this Destroyer Himself, which is what Time Travel is... unless you travel just like an observer I suppose.

Comment: @TheDestroyer THis question is about time travel and that one was about Time Dilation

Comment: @AnkitSharma Yeah. I think OP of second question meant "Time travel" but what he is mentioning in question is time dilation. Hanugm must edit his question to make it clear.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, time travel is mentioned in Srimad Bhagavatam.**

> [SB 9.3.29](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9/3/29) Taking his own daughter, Revatī, Kakudmī went to Lord Brahmā in Brahmaloka, which is transcendental to the three modes of material nature, and inquired about a husband for her.
>
> [SB 9.3.30](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9/3/30) — When Kakudmī arrived there, Lord Brahmā was engaged in hearing musical performances by the Gandharvas and had not a moment to talk with him. Therefore Kakudmī waited, and at the end of the musical performances he offered his obeisances to Lord Brahmā and thus submitted his long-standing desire.
>
> [SB 9.3.31](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9/3/31) — After hearing his words, Lord Brahmā, who is most powerful, laughed loudly and said to Kakudmī: **O King, all those whom you may have decided within the core of your heart to accept as your son-in-law have passed away in the course of time.**
>
> [SB 9.3.32](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9/3/32) — **Twenty-seven catur-yugas have already passed.** Those upon whom you may have decided are now gone, and so are their sons, grandsons and other descendants. You cannot even hear about their names.

Comment: This is again Not exactly time travelling. This shows relative times of different worlds similar to the one i mentioned in the question also this was referred(Wiki-link) by sysinit in the comments earlier. Anyway nice  instance but i'm looking for some other real **Time Travelling** account.

Comment: Time travelling is something like, character of Mahabharatha (28th Dwapara Yuga) going to Ramayana times (24th Treta Yuga). I am not sure that's possible (within in this universe) and mentioned in Hindu Scriptures.

Comment: In Shiva Purana Sati meets Rama... that could be through time travelling... ie. Coming to future...